# Error on @Override annotation with interface implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

**I am using JRE 1.6 version and aware of JRE 1.5 trouble while using `@Override` with interface.**

I imported a new project (Spring + Maven ) and Eclipse giving error on every `@Override` annotation whenever any interface method is overridden.

Things I tried till now

1. Checked project and workspace specific JRE and compliance level, It is set to 1.6 version.
   [image]
2. Checked JRE library on build path, it is also same.
3. Changed Java version in project facet to 1.6 (Dont know if it will help)
   [image]
4. Did Maven clean and install (hundred times till now)
5. Disabled error / warning for Annotations still no luck [image]
6. Eclipse restart (Stupid thing but helps me lots of time)
7. Last option will be deleting all .setting and .project files if I dont get anything else to try.

---

**Edit 1:**
I am getting following error

```
The method XXX of type XXX must override a superclass method.
```

---

**Edit 2:**
Code Sample
Interface declaration

```
public interface HelperService {   
    public RequisitionTypeDTO getRequisitionTypeDTO(int id) throws Exception;  
}
```

Implementation:

```
   @Service
   public class HelperServiceImpl implements HelperService{   
   @Override  // Getting error for this line
   public RequisitionTypeDTO getRequisitionTypeDTO(int id) throws Exception{
                         // Bla Bla Bla 
      }  
   }
```

---

**EDIT 3:**
I am able to build and run my application successfully irrespective of this errors. Just not happy with red error flags all over the source code.

Comment: It's probably nothing, but since you ruled out everything else: Are those really `@override` annotations? It *should* be `@Override` with a capital O.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Ya its with big `O`. Please tell me how its matter?

Comment: @Ajinkya: annotation names are class names, so they are case-sensitive like everything else. It *could have* been some entirely unrelated `override` annotation (but even if it were it's unlikely to produce these kinds of errors). So to summarize: it's not relevant, but I saw nothing else that hinted at a problem.

Comment: Sorry, can't help unless you show what is the error you're getting. Also, try creating a new Java Project and create a class that implements `Runnable`. See if you still get the error on the `@Override` for the `run()` method implementation.

Comment: @adarshr: I have added error details. Not getting this error with other projects.

Comment: My only suspicion is the project facet is incorrect. Usually there will be dependency issues. For instance, if you change Java to 6, you can't use Servlet 3.0 and the facet editor would complain.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the project facet editor also?

Comment: Please add an example interface and method to the question.

Comment: @adarshr: I have added screenshot of project facet editor.

Comment: @beerbajay: Added sample code.

Comment: Is your Eclipse set to *Build Automatically*? Otherwise, have you tried a full build? Eclipse wouldn't build automatically if you have back-dated your system, for example. There could also be some other *Build Path* errors in your project which may be preventing a full build. You can do a `Window > Show View > Markers` and see if you have any errors that could be preventing a project build.

Comment: @adarshr: It is on `build automatically` option. And I am able to build and run my application even with this thousand errors.

Comment: @Ajinkya Make a small change in your code and try running to see if you see the changes. You could be running stale classes and be under the impression that it is building properly :)

Comment: @adarshr: Error gone. Just added Java builder to project.

Comment: @All: Dont know how builder is related to this and dont know why nothing was selected in builder option. Still thanks a lot for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realized no Builder is selected for current project. Selected `Java Builder` and boom. No more red flags all over the code.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Check if the `RequisitionTypeDTO` in interface is the same type as `RequisitionTypeDTO` in implementation (different imports).

If ok then try adding `maven-compiler-plugin`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and `Maven`->`Update project configuration...` from context menu of your project - because that is the way you should set compilation jre.

And of course try `mvn clean`, in Eclipse `Project`->`Clean...`

If everything fails create new simple project with minimal code and check if there is the same error.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.the problem waas with the builders applied to project.

Answer (score 3):

I got this too, and I *did* have a "Java Builder" set. Further investigation showed that the problem was that my "Compiler Compliance Level" was set to 1.5 rather than 1.6.

Comment: That is, this question is effectively similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods

Comment: Same here. A Maven 'update project' on a project where the POM didn't have a Java version specified triggered the change.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue (this was with code that was working perfectly).

A few minutes ago I stopped seeing classes in the same package ([Maven java project in eclipse doesn't see classes in same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618017/maven-java-project-in-eclipse-doesnt-see-classes-in-same-package)) and 'fixed' that error by doign a Maven -> update project.

This changed my compiler level to 1.5 and caused a new issue i.e. this topic

(Fixed by explicitly changing my compiler level)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
For me the problem was "Java" was not selected in properties -> project facet
Even though I had my jre and compiler level set correctly I still had the problem.